# Two cameras using gscam

Tags: gscam, camera

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello,

How can I start two cameras using gscam? What i have to change in:
export GSCAM_CONFIG="v4l2src device=/dev/video0 ! video/x-raw-rgb ! ffmpegcolorspace"

and here:

rosrun image_view image_view image:=/gscam/image_raw

To see video from two cameras in one window?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/61311/two-cameras-using-gscam/) by [dada81](https://answers.ros.org/users/4730/dada81/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2013-04-22

Post score: 3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You could use one terminal per camera and export in the first /dev/video0 and the second /dev/video1? You should then use a separate launch file to prevent that both publish to the same topic. Not sure if this possible, some camera implementations are a little basic.

With Rviz you can view the two streams. rosrun rviz rviz and add the streams.

---

Originally posted by [davinci](https://answers.ros.org/users/3014/davinci/) with karma: 2573 on 2013-04-22

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0